# Delete ex-developer workspace

Tags: workspace

I have a new developer.  He uses an ex-developer box with a mapped workspace to

`C:\TFS10`

I tried mapping the new guy to the same location (switching folders is **not** an option due to FinalBuilder constraints).  I get an error saying the workspace already exists for EXDEVELOPERUSERID.  How can I delete the workspace in TFS of this ex-dev?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a couple of options. Firstly open a visual studio 2010 command prompt and use the [TF Workspace command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y901w7se%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Alternatively install the [TFS sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/) and use the UI to search for the workspace on the server and delete it from there.

For both of these methods you need to be running as an account that has permissions to delete another users workspace (project administrator)